# Align 3d object in unity to gyro of device

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, quaternions

I have a 3d object in unity which i want to have the exact orientation as the device (currently android).

I tried using:

```
transform.rotation = Input.gyro.attitude;
```

After getting to know the unity right-hand inverse to left-hand of the gyro:

```
Quaternion q = Input.gyro.attitude;
transform.rotation = new Quaternion (q.x, q.y, -q.z, -q.w);
```

but they all gave incorrect results, where the object was twirling around an axis when i turned the device from right to left.

When i am trying this:

```
    Quaternion q = Input.gyro.attitude;
    q = new Quaternion (q.x, q.y, -q.z, -q.w);
    transform.rotation = q * Quaternion.Euler (-90f, 0f, 0f)
```

the object is facing west instead of up.

Which manipulation on the rotation should i use? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although my original question was how to attach an object to the gyroscope, I managed to solve the problem the other way around.

The solution i found was to attach the camera itself to the gyroscope:

```
        Quaternion q = gyro.attitude;
        q = new Quaternion (q.x, q.y, -q.z, -q.w);
        Camera.main.transform.rotation = q;
        Camera.main.transform.Rotate(90f, 0f, 0f, Space.World);
```

After that, i attached the object as a child of the camera, which hacked the problem.

Specifically this works on android, didn't check it on ios.